# How can I fix the name error uglifyjs is giving me creating a bundle?

Tags: javascript, bundle, uglifyjs

I'm using Uglifyjs to create a bundle of old javascript (pre ES2015) files, like this:

```
uglifyjs *.js -o bundle.js
```

It works well for a part of the project, but one file contains the new three dots syntax and I get the following error

```
that.cmd = function(cmd, ...args) {
                         ^
ERROR: Name expected
```

Does Uglifijs work only with the old javascript syntax? How can I fix the problem?

Edit: I had two different versions installed, using uglify-js-es6 2.8.9 it's all ok!

Comment: What version of uglify are you using?

Comment: uglify-js 3.0.27 (uglify-js-es6)

Comment: I had two different versions installed, using uglify-js-es6 2.8.9
it's all ok!

Comment: I quickly recreated your example and I am experiencing the same problem with version `uglify-js 3.4.9`

Comment: please note that two versions exist: uglify-js and uglify-js-es6, now I'm using the latter

Comment: If you fix your problem yourself you shall add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `--parse` options are specifying your intended bundle output and ensure you are using the version or variant that includes ES6 capability.

Looks like `uglify-js-es6` works for the above TC-39 Call constructor feature